# Working with nodejs api

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to nodejs and this is my first app. I am trying to use a nodejs API called event registry to get some data. Implementation below:

```
app.get('/eventregistry', function(req,res){
    console.log("dfsdfdf");
    var er = new erBase.EventRegistry({apiKey: "API Key"});
    er.getConceptUri("syria").then((conceptUri) => {
        var q = new erBase.QueryArticlesIter(er, {conceptUri: conceptUri, sortBy: "date"});
        q.execQuery((items) => {
            for(var item of items) {
                console.info(item);
            }
        })
    });
});
```

My problem is when I run the server and go to the route nothing happens. My event package is installed and required as well. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you must send a response back to client using that res object in your callback function

Comment: You also don't have any error handling so if `er.getConceptUri()` rejects, then you won't do anything.  Also, is there really no way for `q.execQuery()` to have an error?

Comment: If anyone looking for Nodejs API boilerplate with Expressjs and MongoDB. Try this: https://github.com/maitraysuthar/rest-api-nodejs-mongodb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must send a response back to client using that `res` object in your callback function:

```
app.get('/eventregistry', function(req,res){
    console.log("dfsdfdf");
    var er = new erBase.EventRegistry({apiKey: "API Key"});
    er.getConceptUri("syria").then((conceptUri) => {
        var q = new erBase.QueryArticlesIter(er, {conceptUri: conceptUri, sortBy: "date"});
        q.execQuery((items) => {
            for(var item of items) {
                console.info(item);
            }
            res.status(200).json(items); // as example
        })
    });
});
```

I highly recommend you reading express documentation, exceptionally their [Response Object](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res) part.